# Как происходит расширение примитивных типов

Tags: java, типы-данных

Предположим, у нас есть такой код:

```
long a = 0x1_0000_0000L + 0xCAFE_BABE;
System.out.println(a == 0x1_CAFE_BABEL);
```

Почему будет выведен `false`? По идее, число `0xCAFE_BABE` должно быть автоматически расширено до типа `long`, и уже после этого должно произойти сложение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

а оно и происходит. Просто `0xCAFE_BABE` - отрицательное (!) поэтому оно и приводится к отрицательному long - у.

Т.е. `(long)(0xCAFE_BABE)` (именно в такой записи) - это `FFFF_FFFF_CAFE_BABE` что немного не то, на что вы рассчитывали. Поэтому числа больше `7FFF_FFFF` в подобных ситуациях нужно писать *только* с суффиксом L.